# scan and connect in react-native-ble-plx not working

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to implement tyre pressure reading functionality in my app, currently for testing purpose instead of a using a pressure sensor(ble device) I am using my wireless head phones(Samsung ITFIT band) to connect to [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/) but on scanning the devices I did not get anything(headphone not visible on scanning), this is my scanning code:-

```
manager.startDeviceScan( null, null,(error, device) => {
console.log("inside startdevice scan")        //not getting executed
})
```

Is this the problem with the headphone that I am trying to connect or anything else please help me

Answer (score 0):

Headphones usually use Bluetooth Classic and not Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). BLE is designed for low power applications and does not include a profile for continuous   music streaming.

Please use a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) for testing. You will only find BLE devices that are currently advertising their presence, but the devices should be the same oney you can find using your own app.

There are different ways to simulate a BLE device, called a peripheral, for testing purposes. For example if you have another phone you can use [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) and start a GATT server.

I recommend you to start developing your pressure sensor and testing it using a generic BLE scanner app. If everything works start developing your app. If something fails afterwards you can be sure your app produces the problem.